# Import a .fil file in OpenOffice calc

Tags: csv, import, openoffice-calc

I have the exe of an old VB application. It seems that this app saves the data in .hat files, txt files, and a .fil file. I'm trying to create a new app and I want to migrate the data in OpenOffice Base. I managed to migrate the .txt, .hat files but I have a problem migrating the .fil file. I open it in Calc or Writer but I can not understand what is the delimeter that separates the fields.

What is a .fil file?

If anyone is interested I can send them the .fil to take a look.

I dont seem to make any progress so I would appreciate any help I get.
Thanks in advance
Vivi

Part of the output after passing the file from od.

```
0000000  \r  \n 305 353 345 343 367 357 362     344 345 365 364 345 361
0000020 357 360 341 350 357 375 362     365 360 335 361 364 341 363 347
0000040 362     352 341 351     341 360 345 351 352 357 355 351 363 364
0000060 351 352 336     352 357 351 353 337 341 362     352 341 351
0000100   O   D   .
0000120
*
0002160       9   /   3   /   2   0   0   9  \r  \n 315 345 357 345 354
0002200 366 341 355 351 363 350 345 337 362     323 304     365 360 374
0002220     341 343 371 343 336     341 360 374     347 354 345 361 376
0002240 355     352 341 351     355 345 357 345 354 366 341 355 351 363
0002260 350 345 337 363 341     301 325     363 364 334 344 351 357
0002300 311 311     360 361 357 362     311 311 311   ,     301 361 355
0002320 347 364 351 352 374     357 351 352 357 343 345 355 345 351 341
0002340 352 374     351 363 364 357 361 351 352 374     301 325     352
0002360 341 351     323 304   .      \r  \n 304 351 341 352 357 360 336
0002400     352 341 360 355 337 363 354 341 364 357 362     360 361 357
0002420     347 354 345 361 376 355     352 341 351     344 351 341 364
0002440 341 361 341 367 335 362     363 364 375 363 347 362   .
0002460
*
0004040                             313 345 365 352 374   .
0004060
*
0005720                                                       M   A   L
0005740   E
0005760
*
0006040                                                     323 352 353
0006060 347 361 337 341     345 360 351 343 341 363 364 361 337 357 365
0006100   .  \r  \n 330 365 367 361 334     334 352 361 341   .  \r  \n
0006120
*
0007740             303   . 341 337 354 341 364 357 362   ,     342 351
0007760 357 367 347 354 351 352 374     352 341 351     343   . 357 375
0010000 361 371 355     352   . 366   .   (   1   2   /   0   8   )   ,
0010020  \r  \n   2   /   0   9       G   l   u   :   1   4   6   ,
0010040 353 357 351 360 334     352   . 366   .       H   b   A   1   c
0010060   :   6   .   3   .
0010100
*
0014060                     341 341 341 341 341     323
0014100                                       1   1
0014120
0014140                             317     302
0014160                                             317
0014200             305 353 345 343 367 357 362     344 345 365 364 345
0014220 361 357 360 341 350 357 375 362     365 360 335 361 364 341 363
0014240 347 362     352 341 351       C   P   K   .
0014260
*
0016400       1   3   /   3   /   2   0   0   9  \r  \n 321 375 350 354
0016420 351 363 347     301 325      \r  \n   1   1   /   0   8     355
0016440 357 363 347 353 345 337 341         343 351 341     346 334 353
0016460 347     345 354 335 364 357 365 362     352 341 351     341 365
0016500 356 347 354 335 355 347     301 325     354 345     365 360 345
0016520 361 364 361 357 366 337 341     301 321     352 357 351 353 337
0016540 341 362   ,     341 354 366 351 342 353 347 363 364 361 357 345
0016560 351 344 357 360 334 350 345 351 341     311 311     363 364 341
0016600 344 337 357 365   ,     341 350 347 361 371 354 334 364 371 363
0016620 347     352 341 361 371 364 337 344 371 355       3   5   %
0016640 352 341 351       M   R   I     345 343 352 345 366 334 353 357
0016660 365     354 345     354 351 352 361 357 351 363 367 341 351 354
0016700 351 352 336     345 343 352 345 366 341 353 357 360 334 350 345
0016720 351 341     352 341 351     350 334 353 353 351 357     354 345
0016740     341 355 364 351 363 364 361 345 360 364 336     351 363 367
0016760 341 351 354 337 341     352 357 361 365 366 341 337 357 365
0017000 364 357 351 367 376 354 341 364 357 362   .         305 360 337
0017020 363 347 362     341 365 356 347 354 335 355 347       C   P   K
0017040     341 360 374     364 347 355     360 361 376 364 347     355
0017060 357 363 347 353 345 337 341     360 345 361 337     364 341
0017100   1   0   0   0  \r  \n
0017120
*
0020260                             324 361 357 367 341 337 357     364
0020300 357       1   9   9   1     354 345     360 353 341 363 364 351
0020320 352 336     344 335 361 354 341 364 357 362     301 321     342
0020340 361 341 367 337 357 355 341   .  \r  \n 312 341 364 334 367 361
0020360 347 363 347     341 353 352 357 374 353     363 364 357     360
0020400 341 361 345 353 350 374 355   .  \r  \n 314 360 341 354 360 334
0020420 362     301 305 305   .     314 341 354 334     301 325     352
0020440 341 351     355 345 366 361 357 360 334 350 345 351 341   .
0020460
*
0022140                                                       M   A   A
0022160   L   E
0022200
*
0022260                                                     352   . 366
0022300   .     301 320   :   1   3   5   /   9   5   m   m   H   g
0022320
*
0024160               2   /   0   9       W   B   C   :   5   6   0   0
0024200   ,       H   t   :   4   0   ,       M   C   V   :   8   1   ,
0024220       p   l   t   :   2   2   2   0   0   0   ,       T   K   E
0024240   :   1   5   ,       G   l   u   :   1   0   5   ,       U   r
0024260   L   3   4   ,       C   r   :   1   .   1   ,       C   h   o
0024300   l   :   1   8   0   ,       H   D   L   :   5   5   ,       L
0024320   D   L   :   1   0   0   ,       T   R   I   G   :   1   2   4
0024340   ,       S   G   O   T   :   6   3   ,       S   G   P   T   :
0024360   1   0   9   ,       A   L   P   :   5   8   ,     343   G   T
0024400   :   3   4   ,       C   P   K   :   1   6   1   0   ,     343
0024420   . 357 375 361 371 355     354 345       +   +     353 345 375
0024440 352 371 354 341     357 375 361 371 355     352   . 366   .
0024460
*
0030300
0030305
```

Comment: Yeah, wow, pass `-c` to `od` as I suggested. And indent with 4 spaces, or highlight it and press the code button.

Comment: This isn't a delimited file, it's a structured file. And unfortunately the structure metadata isn't in the piece you gave. It's definitely encoded text though.

Comment: I'm sending you the beginning of the file.  Could the metadada be these?

Comment: No, it's too sparse and too regular. Try the end.

Comment: I'm sending you the end of the file but there are only data there.  If the structure it's not in the file where can it be?  The friend that wants this app migrated to a database only has an exe, one .txt file, this .fil file, a .hat file and .jpg file in the installation CD of this app.

Comment: ... Doesn't look like it's in here at all. In that case the metadata would be in one of the other files, maybe even in the executable.

Comment: They are not in the other files.  I looked in the .txt, .hat files.  Do you have any suggestions?  The only thing I can do is manually migrate the data?  (288 pages when opened in Writer :-)).

Answer (score 0):

Passing the file to [`od`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) (preferably with `-c`) will show you what characters are being used.

Comment: Hello Ignacio, thank you very for the quick reply.  I'm trying to find out what od is.  When I do I'll notify you if that solved my problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: I linked to a package that provides it for Windows.

Comment: Hey!  Thanks a lot for your help.  I've managed to run od but still dont have a clue what is the delimeter.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and add the output so that everyone can see it.